# Archive::Any gives IO error

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin, cpan

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $archive_files = "C:\\Temp\\FREMOTE\\test.zip";
sub extract_archive($$);

extract_archive($archive_files, "C:\\Temp\\FREMOTE\\TEST\\");
extract_archive("C:\\Temp\\FREMOTE\\TEST\\testb.zip",
                "C:\\Temp\\FREMOTE\\TEST\\testb\\");

sub extract_archive($$) { 
    my $archive_file = shift;
    my $extract_dir  = shift;
    if (!  -d "$extract_dir") {
        mkdir $extract_dir;
    }
    use Archive::Any;
    my $archive = Archive::Any->new($archive_file);
    if($archive->extract($extract_dir)) {
        print "Extracted $archive_file into $extract_dir\n";
        undef $archive;
    } else {
        print "Failed to extracted $archive_file into $extract_dir\n";
    }
}
```

I got the following error. How do I resolve it?

```
IO error: write error during copy : Bad file descriptor
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Archive/Any.pm line 193.
IO error: write error during copy : Bad file descriptor
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Archive/Any.pm line 193.
IO error: write error during copy : Bad file descriptor
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Archive/Any.pm line 193.
IO error: write error during copy : Bad file descriptor
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Archive/Any.pm line 193.
```

Comment: Lack of Carp use in CPAN modules is probably my biggest dislike about the perl ecosystem.

Comment: its true about perl ecosystem

Comment: The error is actually specified in [`Archive::Zip::Member` at line 1068](https://metacpan.org/source/Archive::Zip::Member#L1068). In fact, Carp is used for the error, but a call stack trace would have been helpful… Happy ongoing bug hunt…

Comment: You can force a stack trace with [Carp::Always](http://p3rl.org/Carp::Always).

Comment: I tried your code in both Windows and Linux and had no issues unzipping files. You are certain that the zip files are not corrupt and this error occurs for any zip file?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could get a sample of your zip file in order to remake the error. Also, how large is this zip file? Does this happen across machines or only on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with the following code.  Using two known-good zip files, I added the second zip file into the first - to reproduce what I believe you are doing.  With the original code I kept receiving an error during the extraction of the second file:

```
Extracted C:\Temp\colorbox-master.zip into C:\Temp\FREMOTE\TEST\<br>
Can't call method "extract" on an undefined value at Perl-1.pl line 19.
```

Different from your error, but fixed with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $archive_files = "C:\\Temp\\colorbox-master.zip";

extract_archive($archive_files, "C:\\Temp\\FREMOTE\\TEST\\");
extract_archive("C:\\Temp\\FREMOTE\\TEST\\easybox-v1.3.zip", "C:\\Temp\\FREMOTE\\TEST\\testb\\");

sub extract_archive {
    my $archive_file = shift;
    my $extract_dir  = shift;
    if (!-d "$extract_dir") {
        mkdir $extract_dir;
    }
    use Archive::Any;
    my $archive = Archive::Any->new($archive_file);
    if($archive->extract($extract_dir)) {
        print "Extracted $archive_file into $extract_dir\n";
        undef $archive;
    } else {
        print "Failed to extracted $archive_file into $extract_dir\n";
    }
}
```

Extracted C:\Temp\colorbox-master.zip into C:\Temp\FREMOTE\TEST\
Extracted C:\Temp\FREMOTE\TEST\easybox-v1.3.zip into C:\Temp\FREMOTE\TEST\testb\

Note that I had just installed the 'Archive::Any-0.0932' module (ActiveState Perl) so I may have a different (fixed) version.  You may want to check that your module is at the most recent version.  And that your zip files are not broken.